# Udev Rule no longer works

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udev

I wrote a simple udev rule to mount my compact flash card reader to a writeable device node. The rule was working earlier, but seems to have stopped for some reason, I was editing the file before, but now it just contains:

```
KERNEL=="/dev/sd*", ATTRS{model}=="Compact Flash   ", SYMLINK+="compactflash-%k", MODE=="0666"
```

The file is called `90-cf-rule.rules` and is located in `/etc/udev/rules.d`. If someone could point out what's wrong I'd be really grateful.

It looks like `udevd` is still running, and I run `udevadm trigger` after editing the rules file. I've tried plugging and unplugging the device. I'm also certain that the model matches as I copied and pasted from `udevadm info` and have had this rule working!

Comment: What distro are you using?  This may be a question for SuperUser.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu. I have fixed the error, will post my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct udev filter is:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{model}=="Compact Flash   ", SYMLINK+="compactflash-%k", MODE=="0666"
```

ie. The /dev/ is not required in front of the KERNEL argument. I must have put this in while editing the file earlier.